# Why is [(ngModel)] not mapping initial '-' (minus sign)?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ngmodel

.html code

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="input_value" (keyup)="printValue()" />
```

.ts code

```
input_value: any;
...
...  
printValue(){
 console.log(this.input_value)
}
```

Outputs:

```
Input--> Outputs

111  -->   111

-5   -->   5
-    -->   ""
-8 (prepend a minus sign after I Enter a number) -> -8
```

Everytime I try to enter a minus sign it only takes empty string, but if Enter a number and then prepend minus sign it works fine.

How can I make it work so that I can enter a minus sign first and then add number?

Comment: you mean entering simple " minus sign -" its not outputting?

Comment: yes, it takes it as an empty string, 
It converts the input field to blank again

Comment: the input is `type="number"`, minus is not a number, some navigators give you null, another one ""

Comment: i see that, was wondering if theres a way to make it work ?.. because a html input type number allows you to do it

Comment: What would you expect it to print? `-0`? `-` by itself isn't a value/number and shouldn't be treated as one.

Comment: well minus isn't a number type. Have you tried with type text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- (minus)` by itself isn't a value, so it'll print `null`.

It does otherwise work though: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-minus

Comment: Like your shared example, it isn't binding to the input field till I provide it a numeric value... if i start the input with a minus sign, the input  binds itself back to null and shows empty

Comment: The user is forced to enter a number and then prepend the - sign

Comment: No, you can type `- and 5` or `5 and prepend -`, there is no difference.

Comment: Yea thats the thing, it should work but the input field turn blank after I enter the - sign, anyways it works on your demo, so its not something to do with ngmodel, i'll try to fix it some other way, thanks

Comment: I see. Directives and HostListeners can modify elements, so you may want to check if that can be the culprit.